# Change format in access pass-through query

Tags: sql-server, ms-access

When I run my SQL procedure in Access, which returns a table, the data in table are in unexpected format. Is there a way to change the format of the result table?

Result format: 1.00 XDR
Expected format: 1.00

Comment: By any chance, is the value *actually* stored in the database `'1.00 XDR'` rather than there being 2 columns for the value and currency (or whatever XDR represents) (with the values `1.00` and `'XDR'` respectively).

Comment: The value in database is in correct format. I don't know what you mean.. Only access shows wrong format

Comment: It is not about a "correct" format. It is about what data type the field of the table has? And if _text_, are the values like "1.00 XDR"? [XDR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special_drawing_rights) is a pretty uncommon currency.

Comment: Data type in database is decimal(10,4). In access it always shows XDR as a currency.

Comment: It seems to be an antivirus that does its thing: https://www.microsoft.com/security/blog/2020/09/22/microsoft-unified-siem-xdr-modernize-security-operations/

Comment: _In access it always shows XDR as a currency_ It is your application code that is doing this. Without seeing that code there is little to suggest.

Comment: The thing is, access always put currency number format as a default format, when I create a table or query, it always shows XDR number format first, then I change it and it's okay, the problem is in pass-through query only, in my sql procedure I created a temp table with **decimal(10,4)** values. Now I see, only decimal(10,4) does this. I have another columns with data type decimal(10,2) and it has the format that I want in access pass-through query. I want to keep the decimal(10,4), but without 'XDR'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the right solution. In the Sql procedure I **format decimal(10,4)** values, for example: select format (column1, 'N4') as column1 from ...